# MySql 5.6 Column level Query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying the following SQL in MySQL 5.6:

```
select Test=1 from ALL_FILES_INFO;
```

However I am getting an error.

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Test' in 'field list'

it is some thing Like this

```
Select Name,
       Amount=(select Amount from EmployeeAmount where EmployeeName=Name)
 from Employee;
```

The same code is running properly In Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Perhaps it's just my lack of familiarity with SQL Server, but what is a "*column level query*"?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Should this be equal to `SELECT Test FROM ALL_FILES_INFO WHERE Test = 1`?

Comment: It would be good if you could tell us what error your getting?

Comment: @Marcel-- we need to calculate amount from another tables instead of 1 . so i doing in this way

Comment: @ajtrichards :- Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Test' in 'field list'

Comment: maybe you mean `select 1 as Test from ALL_FILES_INFO;` but makes no sense to me :D

Comment: So, if `Test` is not a column name... what do you intend it to mean?  Perhaps some example data and expected results would help.

Comment: @Eggyal := i have modify the Question please check

Comment: @Eggyal :=Wee need More Calculation among different tables we don't want to use joins

Comment: @Shashank: You'll almost certainly find that your query can still be performed using a join (and quite probably it'd be more efficient too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has an alternate way of stating column aliases, this will as far as I can tell do the exact same thing and work on both MySQL and SQL Server;

```
SELECT 1 AS Test from ALL_FILES_INFO;
```

[SQLFiddle for SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f0af/4)
[SQLFiddle for MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f0af/4)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off joining your tables than using your correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Employee.Name, EmployeeAmount.Amount
FROM   Employee
  JOIN EmployeeAmount ON EmployeeAmount.EmployeeName = Employee.Name
```